# How to disable the color of the cell when is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to disable the cell color when is selected but I can't do it yet I've tried with a lot of advices but stills turning white when is selected, could you help me please? I've tried with this line of code

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

in this two delegates:
 cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPAth

And keep doing the same, that I want to disappear is the withe view that is under the view it's rounded with the blue color, so When I touch the cell I just want the rounded the view the view that contains the info without the other.

[Exapmle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG4jh.jpg)

Comment: This is a custom cell. Show some code.

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

For removing the color behind the cell, set the cells 'selectionStyle:`to be`UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`. This will force **all** cell background colorization during and after selection to be removed (no color).

**OR** simply assign the style in a `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Remove the cell's style by setting to 'None'
    self.selectionStyle = .None;

    // Do whatever else  you need to here

}
```

If still would like some sort of selection / colorized interaction, make the content view the **same** size as the cell, and add padding between the cells that are being added to the parent view using the delegate methods, or override the rect drawing in your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, though it was caused by a different thing. I set the cell selectionStyle to .none but the issue was in this part the background color of the cell was on default which is white color and I had to set it no clear color which was the problem.

[image: Solution]